# Fork process from module [node.js]

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to create module for compresing images but fork inside module not working...

Could someone help me with this?

Here is `compress.js` module:

```
var editor = require('./editor');

    module.exports = function (imageUrl) {

    // We need to spawn a child process so that we do not block 
    // the EventLoop with cpu intensive image manipulation 
        var childProcess = require('child_process').fork(editor);
    //
        childProcess.on('message', function (message) {
            console.log(message);
        });
        childProcess.on('error', function (error) {
            console.error(error.stack);
        });
        childProcess.on('exit', function () {
            console.log('process exited');
        });
        childProcess.send(imageUrl);

        return childProcess;
    };
```

compress staff, `editor.js`:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
var imageResize = require('gulp-image-resize');

function processImg (filesrc) {
 return gulp.src(filesrc)

    // compress and save
  .pipe(imagemin({optimizationLevel: 5}))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('uploads/og'))


  .pipe(imageResize({
    width: 600,
    height: 600,
    crop: true
  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('uploads/600'))


  .pipe(imageResize({
    width: 290,
    height: 390,
    crop: true
  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('uploads/290'))


  .pipe(imageResize({
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    crop: true
  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('uploads/100'));

}

process.on('message', function (images) {

  console.log('Image processing started...');
  var stream = processImg(images);
  stream.on('end', function () {
    process.send('Image processing complete');
    process.exit();
  });
  stream.on('error', function (err) {
    process.send(err);
    process.exit(1);
  });
});

module.exports = {};
```

Here is error:

module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

> Error: Cannot find module '/home/master/Documents/rs-api/[object
>   Object]'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
>       at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
>       at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
>       at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
>       at bootstrap_node.js:509:3 process exited